# Для чего нужен этот парамерт RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Для чего нужен этот парамерт RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$  ?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
```

вот так мы меняем дерикторию или запрещаем доступ к всему из папки папки mime

```
RewriteRule ^mime[/].+$ doc/index [L]
```

---

**Вопрос:** А зачем нужна вот эта щтука, без неё все работает ?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ #Ресурс, запрошенный в строке HTTP запроса.
```

Мысли в слух: Может быть он нужен чтобы не скачали файлы в папки при помощи модифицированных каких-нибудь запросов, и эта функция их проверяет.

Comment: Вообще-то, эта штука говорит, что запрос идет на главную страницу сайта в таком виде _https://site.ru/ и по идее представленные `RewriteCond` и `RewriteRule` вместе ни когда не сработают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае проверяется происходит ли запрос главной страницы. И  если да, то выполняется правило ниже.

> Строки RewriteCond - задают условия для срабатывания следующего за
>   ними правила RewriteRule. Условий может быть несколько, они
>   накладываются по правилу AND. Но можно изменить правило на OR с
>   помощью флага OR.
>
> RewriteRule - правило подстановки. Если запрос подходит под
>   вышестоящие проверки и [ШАБЛОН], то применяется правило подстановки.
>   Здесь регулировать поведение также можно с помощью флагов. Флаги есть
>   разные, приведу наиболее часто используемые:

Comment: Так а зачем {REQUEST_URI} нужен если и так все работает?

Comment: Исправил ответ. Что то не проснулся ещё

Comment: То есть в данном случае роли он не играет насколько я понял? Меня прост оридирект интересут.